# Displaying Plotly figures in full screen in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, python-sphinx, plotly-python

I have [large Plotly figures and tables in my Jupyter Notebook and Sphinx-based documentation](https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/programming/strategy-examples/portfolio-construction-model.html). Because the documentation page is already crowded, I would like to give the user an option to

- Display these figures in a full-screen pop-up

or

- Make tables scrollable instead of compressed columns, as the table layout with many columns do not work when embedded on a page

An example of a broken layout:

[image]

Does Plotly.py offer ways to achieve this easily? If it doesn't, can I somehow include external JavaScript on the generated Sphinx documentation page for the same effect?

Comment: In addition to directly specifying the graph size, all margins can be set to 0. `fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=0, b=0))`

Comment: Thank you for the good tip. Even if margins set to zero, it will be still too small.

Comment: Could you please post the data inside `timeline` variable since I could not reproduce this example, and it is very complicated to install this library in my device? I will give you an example how to solve this problem in plotly with the same data in `timeline` variable.

Comment: I don't think there is a value added, making the code repeatable. I can reask the question "how can I display any Plotly figure in the full screen". Whether you can run the code or not is very unlikely to contribute to the answer and any work I to do make this happen would be waste of my time.

Comment: MyBinder service is not ideal and we are moving away from it. If you really really want to run the code [I recommend Visual Studio Code Dev Container](https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/programming/setting-up-development-environment/dev-container/visual-studio-code-docker-dev-container-for-jupyter-notebooks.html) as that is the easiest for an ordinary developer.

Comment: Did you try this line `fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=2000)`? you should remove the previous config in this line `fig.update_layout` instead?

Comment: Another solution to pop up the plot in a full screen is to use the following: `fig.update_layout(autosize=True)` and then `fig.show(renderer="browser")` instead of `display(fig)`

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem to come up with new solutions?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Hamzah. I will check this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest two solutions and I wish one of these solution at least works for you:

- **Horizontal Scrollbar**: deactivate the autosizing option and choose a larger value for the width:

  ```
  fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=2000)
  ```
- **Full-screen mode**: activate the autosizing along with pop the plot up in a browser mode:

  ```
   fig.update_layout(autosize=True) # remove height=800
   fig.show(renderer="browser")  # remove display(fig)
  ```

Comment: Hi Hamzah. While your answer did not fully solve my problem, it's the best one we got 

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thanks and it was my pleasure to help you with your problem. But it was a little hard to solve these problems if we cannot reproduce fully your problem on my machine to solve it completely. That's why I asked how I can reproduce. But at the end, I decided to help with my experience in plotly tool without writing any code. I am also still able to help further if the problem was not resolved completely.